# Bitwise XOR of two files

Tags: c, xor

I have two files that I want to bitwise XOR in C. I pass two file pointers into an XOR function that I am writing. Would it be best to use either `fgetc()` or `getline()` to read in characters, bitwise XOR individually, and write to a file; or is there a superior alternative?

Comment: If your using c, you can only use `fgetc`.because `std::getline` is a C++ function.

Comment: use raw byte slurps, not string versions. otherwise you'll run out of string from one file and have to do all kinds of code gymnastics to keep your pointers synched. e.g. file1 has line "abc\n123" and file2 has "abcdefaasdfasdfasdfasdfsdf\n123". if you read per-line, then you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: If the files are larger than a couple of kb, use `fread` with an as large buffer as you dare. This may well beat the overhead of `fgetc` (once per character) or `getline` (which only works on text files, and also has a malloc overhead).

Comment: Open the file in binary mode (fopen("filename", "rb"), and than use fread(1,...) to read bit by bit until eof

Comment: If the files are .bin, would the implementation change at all?

Comment: No. The `.bin` extension doesn't mean anything. (It doesn't even imply anything about the file format.)

Comment: As Marc says, I'd stick with low-level OS read()/write(), don't use any of that C library f-stuff. Treat the files as binary, and when you reach the end of the shorter, you'll have to loop around to its start and read more. The details on this are going to be a pain in the ass (what if a file is smaller than your input buffer, etc.)

Comment: If you're on a sane OS, you can `mmap()` the files.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: "loop around to its start" - not necessarily / depends on application. Probably best to report an error by default and provide options to change the behaviour such as `--loop-on-eof`, `--stop-on-eof` and `--zero-pad-on-eof`.